# Magento2 : Order Items Email Template Adjustment

Tags: magento2, orders, email, email-templates, order-email

I need to add **align="right"** in th(i.e Subtotal, Shipping & Handling, Grand Total) to align right on **tfoot**. I have found that its rendering from the below code under **Magento_Sales/templates/email/items.phtml** file.

```
<tfoot class="order-totals">
        <?= $block->getChildHtml('order_totals') ?>
</tfoot>
```

Can anyone let me know how to edit & modify and add align="right" in that?

[image]

I tried the below solution but the design is breaking. Here is my updated code :

```
<?php $_order = $block->getOrder() ?>
<?php if ($_order): ?>
    <?php $_items = $_order->getAllItems(); ?>
    <table class="email-items" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="item-info" align="left" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Items') ?>
                </th>
                <th class="item-qty" align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Qty') ?>
                </th>
                <th class="item-price" align="left" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Price') ?>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php foreach ($_items as $_item): ?>
            <?php if (!$_item->getParentItem()) : ?>
                <tbody>
                    <?= $block->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
                </tbody>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <table align="right" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
      <tr>
        <th style="padding-right:20px;" align="right"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Subtotal') ?></th>
        <td>  <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $_order->getSubtotal() ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style="padding-right:20px;" align="right"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Shipping & Handling') ?></th>
        <td><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $_order->getShippingAmount() ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style="padding-right:20px;" align="right"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Grant total') ?></th>
        <td><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $_order->getGrandTotal() ?></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </table>
    <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\GiftMessage\Helper\Message')->isMessagesAllowed('order', $_order, $_order->getStore()) && $_order->getGiftMessageId()): ?>
        <?php $_giftMessage = $this->helper('Magento\GiftMessage\Helper\Message')->getGiftMessage($_order->getGiftMessageId()); ?>
        <?php if ($_giftMessage): ?>
            <br />
            <table class="message-gift">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h3><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Gift Message for this Order') ?></h3>
                        <strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('From:') ?></strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getSender()) ?>
                        <br /><strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('To:') ?></strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getRecipient()) ?>
                        <br /><strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Message:') ?></strong>
                        <br /><?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getMessage()) ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Following steps will be useful**

step 1:
      override the items.phtml code

Path:app/design/frontend/Theme/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php $_order = $block->getOrder() ?>
<?php if ($_order): ?>
    <?php $_items = $_order->getAllItems();
     ?>



    <table class="email-items" style="width: 650px; text-align="left"">

            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:#EAEAEA; width: 320px;  ">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Items') ?>
                </td>
                <td style="background-color:#EAEAEA; width: 100px; ">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Sku') ?>
                </td>
                <td style="background-color:#EAEAEA;width: 100px; ">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Qty') ?>
                </td>
                <td style="background-color:#EAEAEA; width: 120px;">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Subtotal') ?>
                </td>
            </tr>

        <?php foreach ($_items as $_item): ?>
            <?php if (!$_item->getParentItem()) : ?>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                <td class="item-info">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $_item->getName()?>
                   <table class="item-info">

            <?php 
            $options = $_item->getProductOptions();           
            $s="";
            $d="";
    if (isset($options['options']) ) {        
        foreach ($options['options'] as $option) {
            $s= $option['label'];
            $d= $option['value'];
        }
    }
            ?>

                       <tr class="item-price">
                           <td class="item-price"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $s?></td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr class="item-price">
                           <td class="item-price"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $d?></td>
                       </tr>
                   </table>
                </td>
                <td class="item-qty">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $_item->getSku() ?>
                </td>
                <td class="item-price">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $_item->getQtyOrdered() ?>
                </td>
                <td class="item-sku">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $_item->getPrice() ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
                </tbody>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?></table>
           <table align="right" style="border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0 1em; width: 650px;">
  <tr>
    <td align="right"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Subtotal') ?></td>
    <td align="right">  <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $_order->getSubtotal() ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Shipping & Handling') ?></td>
    <td align="right"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $_order->getShippingAmount() ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Tax') ?></td>
    <td align="right"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $_order->getTaxAmount() ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th align="right"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Grant total') ?></th>
    <th align="right"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $_order->getGrandTotal() ?></th>
  </tr>
</table>

    <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\GiftMessage\Helper\Message')->isMessagesAllowed('order', $_order, $_order->getStore()) && $_order->getGiftMessageId()): ?>
        <?php $_giftMessage = $this->helper('Magento\GiftMessage\Helper\Message')->getGiftMessage($_order->getGiftMessageId()); ?>
        <?php if ($_giftMessage): ?>
            <br />
            <table class="message-gift">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h3><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Gift Message for this Order') ?></h3>
                        <strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('From:') ?></strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getSender()) ?>
                        <br /><strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('To:') ?></strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getRecipient()) ?>
                        <br /><strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Message:') ?></strong>
                        <br /><?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getMessage()) ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It will works like a charm.

Comment: Hi, I have tried this but the design is breaking. Please check my updated question

Comment: please close your first table before the second table.

Comment: Yes I already added this. Can you please let me know how add SKU in between Items and Qty as like Magento 1?

Comment: see my updated code. It will be useful

Answer (score 2):

I have got this work, I have changed few things & now tis worked for me. Thanks @arun.

```
<?php $_order = $block->getOrder() ?>
<?php if ($_order): ?>
    <?php $_items = $_order->getAllItems(); ?>
    <table class="email-items" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="item-info" align="left" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Items') ?>
                </th>
                <th class="item-qty" align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Qty') ?>
                </th>
                <th class="item-price" align="left" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Price') ?>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php foreach ($_items as $_item): ?>
            <?php if (!$_item->getParentItem()) : ?>
                <tbody>
                    <?= $block->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
                </tbody>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
<tfoot class="order-totals">
  <tr class="subtotal">
        <th style="padding-right:20px;" align="right" colspan="2" scope="row">
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Subtotal') ?> 
        </th>
        <td>
           <span class="price">Rs: <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $_order->getSubtotal() ?></span> 
        </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="shipping">
        <th style="padding-right:20px;" align="right" colspan="2" scope="row">
           <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Shipping & Handling') ?>                    
        </th>
        <td>
           <span class="price">Rs: <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $_order->getShippingAmount() ?></span> 
        </td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="grand_total">
        <th style="padding-right:20px;" align="right" colspan="2" scope="row">
            <strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Grant total') ?></strong>
        </th>
        <td>
            <strong><span class="price">Rs: <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $_order->getGrandTotal() ?></span></strong>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
    </table>
    <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\GiftMessage\Helper\Message')->isMessagesAllowed('order', $_order, $_order->getStore()) && $_order->getGiftMessageId()): ?>
        <?php $_giftMessage = $this->helper('Magento\GiftMessage\Helper\Message')->getGiftMessage($_order->getGiftMessageId()); ?>
        <?php if ($_giftMessage): ?>
            <br />
            <table class="message-gift">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h3><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Gift Message for this Order') ?></h3>
                        <strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('From:') ?></strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getSender()) ?>
                        <br /><strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('To:') ?></strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getRecipient()) ?>
                        <br /><strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Message:') ?></strong>
                        <br /><?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getMessage()) ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

its work fine for me....

I modified the code to obtain 2 decimals for the price...

number_format($_order->getSubtotal(), '2', '.', ',')